# Merging IDs of two spatial objects to create a choropleth map

Tags: r, choropleth, r-sf

**Aim:**
To create a choropleth map by municipalities in Catalonia using population.

**Reproducible data:** 
Ok, so my first step was to download the population and municipality shapefile.

Population: https://www.idescat.cat/cat/idescat/biblioteca/docs/publicacions/gridpoblacio01012016.zip
Municipality borders: http://auriga.icc.cat/bseccen_etrs89/bseccenv10sh1f1_2002a2016_0.zip

**Steps so far:**

Imported both, gave them same coordinates:

```html
catapop<-readOGR("location","rp2016_qtree_level2_ofus_allvar")
catasense<-readOGR("location","bseccenv10sh1f1_20160101_0")

catapop<-spTransform(catapop,CRSobj = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+towsgs84=0,0,0")
catasense<-spTransform(catasense,CRSobj = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+towsgs84=0,0,0")
```

**Issue**

When I look at the data in the shapefiles they contain what I need:

[image: plot(catasense)]

[image: plot(catapop)]

But when I look at the ID's in catasense compared to the ID's in catapop, I don't know what's happening and how I can match the ID's of catapop to catasense.

[image: catasense@data]
[image: catapop@data]

I would like to keep the ID's of catasense "MUNICIPI" since they seem the most standard in the Catalonia public data.

Any ideas on how to match the ID's and create a chloropleth map for population "TOTAL" would be really appreciated!

If there's any clarification needed, let me know!

Comment: Hello, analyzing your population data I see that they are very strange. In the `municip` field there are 947 unique codes, and even doing a treatment in the `ID` fields many of these codes are not within the `ID` field.

Comment: Do you just want to make a graph with the population of Catalonia? Is it viable another population database to do this?

Comment: Exactly! The 947 is correct because there are 947 municipalities. It's the population data that's strange. I'll see if I can get another shapefile that has population for the same number of observations.

Comment: I'm doing something, see if it helps. I took [this data](https://www.idescat.cat/codis/?id=50&n=9) with the codes of the municipalities and I will merge with [this table](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llista_de_municipis_de_Catalunya) that has the population.

Comment: [I made this map](https://imgur.com/5V0tLgP) using the data I gave you

Comment: @WiniciusSabino That's exactly what I would like to do! Could you please briefly explain how? Did you use the 'catasense' shapefile or any other?

Comment: download and open [this html file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u4VAyoMt3v36C1FWPA0RzeKNFxN2YqP-) and see if the map is ok.

Comment: @winiciussabino yes! it's amazing, I want to learn to do this in R. Can you please show me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167176/discussion-between-angela-gill-and-winicius-sabino).

Comment: Yép. Of course, it would be a pleasure to teach you in detail. Let's talk via email or whatever you think is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first step is import this two tables to R

[tab1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l2HUY-qDXPjfrCo2W2UhnDjmLSiPqngU)

[tab2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g94CYRAsEWf0nteB4zEE-2nQ0E4EAmgk)

```
library(readxl) 
pop <- read_excel("Downloads/rp2016/pop.xlsx")  
cod <- read_excel("Downloads/rp2016/cod.xlsx")

names(cod) <- c("Codi", "Nom2", "Codi comarca", "Nom comarca") 
codf <- merge(cod, pop, by.x = "Nom2", by.y = "Nom", all.x = TRUE)

#I make a treatment in the Codi field to put 0 in front of a code that starts with 8.

b <- codf$Codi 

b[grep("^8", b)] <- paste0("0",b[grep("^8", b)]) 

codf$Codi <- b


data2 <- catasense@data 

codf2 <- merge(data2, codf, by.x = "MUNICIPI", by.y = "Codi", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
catasense@data$pop <- codf2$`Població (2016)` 
catasense@data$name <- codf2$Nom2

library(leaflet) 


pal <- colorNumeric("viridis", NULL)


map <- leaflet(catasense) %>% 
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = ~pal(log10(as.numeric(pop))),
              popup = ~paste0("<b>", name, "</b>", " <br> ", "pop:", pop, "<br>"
              ),
              label = ~paste0(name),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                              bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
   addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~log10(pop), opacity = 1.0,
        labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) round(10^x)))


map
```

[image]

```
#you can save leaflet map in html
library(htmlwidgets) 
saveWidget(map, file="cata2.html")
```

[download and open this html file and see the map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cTZ3qOtNNnucx-TxCu4wtzuB_B8-3MYb)